# Can I get glow effect around a gameobject only by using shader in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I mean there's no any script as the component in the main camera, just using shader  to implement the glow effect. Basically I followed this [tutorial](https://willweissman.wordpress.com/tutorials/shaders/unity-shaderlab-object-outlines/) and I've already implemented a nice glow + outline effect.

However, can I only use shader to implement this effect?

Comment: Yes, it's very easy.  I'm not a shader writer but I put one together using Amplify's tool.  I seem to have misplaced the code though.  If you are using Unity 2018 you can use the new Visual Shader editor to get the effect.  You'll see many tutorials online.

Comment: I searched a lot but all ideas are based on post processing...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTYOWRWuBQg  Play and have fun.

Comment: @jiveturkey OtakuFitness need outline glow not your post. Outline glow need an image effect as OtakuFitness says .

Comment: Why do we need post effects? Because we need to calclate neighboring pixels when making blooms, this is not possible for shaders of an object.